# Subscribe to lidar node on another machine and run rviz

Tags: ros, librviz, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have 2 machines on the same network. Machine A has master ros uri and has lidar attached. It is the publisher of lidar topic. I wish to run rviz on machine B to view the output of lidar on machine A. I wrote a subscription method on machine B. When i run rviz, rviz subscribes to machine A instead of using the already subscribed node to machine A.

How do I ask rviz to get data from my subscription instead of having rviz subscribes again to lidar topic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220468/subscribe-to-lidar-node-on-another-machine-and-run-rviz/) by [learner88](https://answers.ros.org/users/25005/learner88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2015-11-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-11-05**:
Can you describe your exact setup, i.e., what nodes on what machine subscribing/publishing which topics - and also what kind of setup you want to achieve. For me, right now, it seems you want to do something that doesn't make sense.

**Comment by [ParitoshKelkar](https://answers.ros.org/users/24321/paritoshkelkar/) on 2015-11-05**:
Does your subscriber on MachineB publish anything? If you are modifying the incoming laser data and then  re-publishing it, you could then on rviz, view only the new 're-published' topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you set

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://<MACHINE_A_IP>:11311
export ROS_IP=<MACHINE_B_IP>
```

in your `.bashrc` file (located in your /home/ directory), and run `source ~/.bashrc` in the terminal, when you run `rviz` in that terminal, you will subscribe to topics in Machine A's ROS network.

Is this what you ask?

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [learner88](https://answers.ros.org/users/25005/learner88/) on 2015-11-06**:
Hi Akif, i am able to run rviz. but when i run roslaunch hector_slam_launch neato.launch, the GUI appeared has error status saying Fixed Frame [map] does not exist. Do you have any idea why? Thank u.

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-11-06**:
`map` frame should be published by your slam node. Can you run `rosrun tf view_frames` and post the resulting tf tree here?

**Comment by [learner88](https://answers.ros.org/users/25005/learner88/) on 2015-11-06**:
here is the tf tree:
odom->base_link(Broadcaster: /map_to_odom; Avg rate: 96.613 Hz; Most recent transform: 1446792454.255,-0.007 sec old; Buffer len: 4.948sec)
base_link->laser(Broadcaster: /base_frame_laser;Avg rate: 96.785Hz; Most recent transform: 1446792454.256,-0.008 sec old; Buffer len: 4.949

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-11-06**:
It seems like no one is transforming from map to odom. For now you can change "Global Options->Fixed Frame" option to `odom` in rviz. After that you can ask a separate question for your setup with hector slam.